# android how to move an activity in the screen

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app and I have an activity open which is the `MainActivity` and it is fit to the screen. Now, I create the other activity which is not fit to the screen and is an overlay on `MainActivity`. The code which I use for this -

```
//Create Pop-up Activity
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;
getWindow().setLayout((int)(width * 0.8),(int)(height * 0.7));
setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Now I want to touch anywhere on this activity and by touching it, move the entire activity anywhere in the screen like move it to top or bottom or like a circle. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Like the Telegram app?

Comment: I dont know telegram app. But I just want to move the activity around the whole screen

Comment: Why don't you use a `View` for this? There must be ways of doing it with Views and Layouts?

Comment: I have an activity actually which has 2 fragments in it. So I need to do it for activity. But is it possible to get view for activity and do ?

Comment: You want to move the Activity which contains 2 Fragments?

Comment: Yeah... The activity is overlayed on other activity. I mean the activity with 2 fragments is not full screen and has window parameters as set in above code